# Plugin CSS does not load because of Theme CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I recently added a [table of contents widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/table-of-contents-plus/) to my sidebar on [this page](https://www.shiftins.com/insurance/homeowners/) but it seems like the style for my sidebar is taking priority over the widget's style. How can I make the widget style sheet more important than my sidebar style sheet?

I am not a developer so specifics are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You probably need to increase the specificity of the widget's CSS rules in order for them to not be overriden by your other rules. Try adding `#toc-widget-2` followed by a space before the CSS rules you have and see if that helps. Try to avoid at all costs using the CSS `!important` declaration. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception for more info

Comment: @j08691 thank you for the response. Where would I find the css rules?